# Referencing a label in my asp.net page from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using VS 2013 VB.

I have the following line of code

```
Dim myLabel As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lbladd"), Label)
```

Whenever I run the page I get the following error

> Conversion from string to type integer is not valid

I have several labels on my asp.net page each with a number at the end of the id which increases by one.  My eventual aim is to loop through each label and add a string to each one using something like the following

```
        For i = 0 To splitAddress.Count - 1

        Dim myLabel As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lbladdress" & i + 1), Label)
        myLabel.Text = splitAddress(i)

    Next
```

Where splitaddress is a list of strings.

I just don't know why its throwing the error and mentioning an integer.

Comment: `i` is an Integer. You should use `i.ToString()` if you want to use it in a string expression. But then you have `+ 1` after it, so I suspect you should have `(i + 1).ToString()`. A better way would be to add the labels to a List and iterate over that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Me.Controls` is of type `ControlCollection` and it is expecting a parameter of type integer, but you are providing a parameter of type string.

To find a control on the page you can use a method `FindControl` of class `Page`.  You can see the info in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can update your code to use this method:

```
Dim myLabel As Label = CType(Me.FindControl("lbladdress" & (i + 1).ToString()), Label)
```

Comment: still get - Conversion from string "lbladdress1" to type 'Integer' is not valid